# How can I create just a part of a circle in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, view, xamarin.ios

[Image I would like to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mVMx.png)

So here is what I would like to have, to get the green circle I create 2 circle one green and one white to "erase" the center and I create a white box to hide the low past I'm sure there is an easier method, but my problem is that I have no idea of how to create the black circle. This circle should also get bigger or smaller in function of the temperature. Do you have an idea of how I could do it?

```
<BoxView Color="#a6ca5c" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" CornerRadius="100" TranslationX="105" TranslationY="430"></BoxView>
<BoxView Color="#f7f7f7" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" CornerRadius="75" TranslationX="130" TranslationY="455"></BoxView>
<BoxView Color="#f7f7f7" WidthRequest="365" HeightRequest="80" TranslationX="20" TranslationY="520"></BoxView>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/geometries#create-an-arcsegment

Comment: You can check the [official document about creating an ellipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/ellipse#create-an-ellipse). And use the circle directly.

Comment: Tanks, those two comments respond to both of my problems.